# SQLCMD load sql script

Tags: sqlcmd

How do I make SQLCMD retrieve any SQL file name using `–i`? (`> .sql`)

If there will always be only 1 file *.sql in the directory?

Answer (score 0):

Does this mean that you want to run any and all .sql files in the directory? If so:

=== PowerShell

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Path 'D:\path\to\sqlfiles' -Filter '*.sql' |
    ForEach-Object {
        & sqlcmd.exe -S 'DBNAME' -i $_.FullName
    }
```

=== CMD

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('DIR /B "D:\path\to\sqlfiles\*.sql"') DO (
    sqlcmd.exe -S DBNAME -i "%%~A"
)
```